# App can't load Angular material theme

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I want to use Angular Material in my MEAN stack app, but I get the following error:

> Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components
>   may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide:
>   https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

In my Angular CLI apps I manage to work with Angular material, but with this app I just can't seem to make it work. It is probably because of the structure of the app:

[image]

As you can see on the image I tried with the @import statement. On the homepage I put a checkbox Material item (here named jjjjjj), but as you can see it doesn't have the theme so it doesn't look good.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and for me it works try to add  this line instead:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

you can choose here the theme you want to apply
[Material theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme)

Comment: I tried that one before as well, but it's the same issue. I think my problem is really related to the structure of my app.

Comment: @tilly put it in your app.component.scss

Comment: can you edit your question with your project structure?

Comment: It's in the original post, the first image. I have tried putting it in the style.css file in the public file, the app.component.css file and as a style element in the index.html (here in the views folder). With all these ways the browser was unable to find the Material theme :/

Comment: @tilly so weired. 
did you installed Material? 

npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
also all your styles should be done in app.component.css and you must import all your components in app.module.ts

Comment: Yeah, I installed it, but still nothing. Very frustrating. Anyway, thanks for your help. I'm going to have to hire something to check it out for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and it was because I was trying to import the material theme into the css file of one of my components. Moving the import statement to the top-level styles.css file worked.

- @angular/core 6.0.0
- @angular/material 6.4.1

Add the line below to the file `src/styles.css`:

```
@import "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```